Handling Error if ActiveCell goes beyond limit (negative)
I have a simple form that goes through a record in a sheet. I'm utilizing Activecell to locate where the record is and it moves up and down. Obviously, there's a limit to how far you can go up (and down but that's way too far right?). How do i error catch this when we go beyond the column header?
Here's the button that I made to go up in the record:
Private Sub btn_Previous_Click() 
ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Select 
Unload Me 
TestUserForm1.Show 
End Sub

Thanks!

Why not use anIf Then statement check the current column number and message the user if they're trying to go beyond the column limits? Otherwise execute OFFSET().

that's the thing, i don't know how what condition to use for that statement. i've googled around and i came across "intersect" but i have no idea how to use it.

If you're writing VBA code, you should study and understand if-then statements. Internet will have plenty of examples. As far as the logic goes, on the button click event, get the column number of the active cell. Get the column number of the 1st header, get the col. number of the last header. If active cell col. is >= 1st header col. and <= last header col., execute your offset statement. Else, execute a message that warns the user and let the procedure end. Search for Excel Activecell.Column.

Row of ActiveCell 'Out of Bounds'
Private Sub btn_Previous_Click()

    Const TOP_ROW As Long = 1 ' adjust!
    Const ROW_OFFSET As Long = -1
    
    With ActiveCell
        If .Row + ROW_OFFSET < TOP_ROW Then
        ' For a positive offset, you have to 'monitor' the bottom row, e.g.:
        'Const BOTTOM_ROW As Long = 1048576
        'Const ROW_OFFSET As Long = 1
        'If .Row + ROW_OFFSET > BOTTOM_ROW Then
            MsgBox "Out of bounds!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        .Offset(ROW_OFFSET).Select
    End With
    
    ' irrelevant:
    'Unload Me
    'TestUserForm1.Show

End Sub

